# Not writing in LogCat

Tags: android, logcat

Shouldn't this be on the LogCat under info? It's not coming up

```
   protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    xp1 = canvas.getWidth()/2;
    **Log.i("Test", "Good");**
    xp2 = canvas.getWidth()/2;
    yp1 = 25;
    yp2 = 760;
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawBitmap(paddle1, xp1,yp1, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(paddle2,xp2,yp2, null);
    Paint white = new Paint();
    white.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.drawText("Score P1:"+ p1Score +" P2: " + p2Score , 700, 20,white );  
}
```

Comment: Are you using Eclipse? Make sure you aren't filtering it out and that the device you are running the app on is highlighted in the Devices window.

Comment: I am using Eclipse, what do you mean by highlighted in the Devices window?

Comment: Open the Devices window and simply click once on the device / emulator that you are using. (Otherwise you might be listening to the wrong device.) You can also try reseting the ADB (also in the Devices window.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this sample image :) (right click to open image in real size)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I didnt type "tag:xxx", I typed just "xxx".